# How to bind element property in Window B to slider value in Window A

Tags: wpf, binding

How does one bind the text box value that is in Window B to the value of a slider in Window A?  I wish this to be two-way binding such that a manual change of the textbox value reflects itself in the slider thumb position.  Element binding within a form is pretty straightforward, but binding between Windows is a mystery to me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the term _form_?

Comment: Generally, you don't bind "form" elements directoy to each-other in WPF. You instead bind the "form" to a ViewModel. There is nothing wrong with binding multiple forms to the same view mdoel.

Comment: 'Window' is what I meant.  Window B is launched from a button on Window A.  Window A has a slider that controls the value in a text box in Window B - currently being set in code behind (one way only).  But if there's a way to set up a two-way binding in XAML, I would prefer that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class with a public property that contains the value you wish to bind to.

Create an instance of the object and set the `DataContext` property of the `TextBox` in `Window` B to that object. Set the `DataContext` property of the `Slider` in `Window` A to the same object. Set the Path property of the `Binding` object for both FrameworkElements to the name of the public property you created. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire the PropertyChanged event in your setters.

Comment: Your answer set me in the right direction. Creating a class with a public property was the key. I then added it as an application level resource in 'App.xaml' and then set the DataContext and Path properties as you suggested. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged was unnecessary. Simply setting the Binding Mode to TwoWay was sufficient. The default 'UpdateSourceTrigger' value of a text box is 'LostFocus'. I changed it to 'PropertyChanged' and all was good.  Thank you.